# Is there a way to display more metadata fields in the Finder list view?

Tags: itunes, finder, mp3, metadata

If I view and sort files in a directory using Finder's list view I seem to be limited to a rather anaemic:

- Name
- Date Modified
- Size
- Kind

Now, take an .mp3 file for example. There is potentially a lot of metadata associated with that file, and this may be a useful basis to sort by.

Is there a way to make available more fields to sort by? Or do I need to resort to a Finder replacement? I realize that iTunes could do most, but not all, of what I want. (iTunes doesn't display some .mp3 metadata fields.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you're (sadly) limited to the fields in the view options windows (<kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd>).

Comment: I think you may be right. I was hoping there was some command-linefu that could be done to expose some more fields.